# Create different shaped pixel?

Tags: java, image, awt, pixel

I was ready through Wikipedia about [Pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel), I found out that a pixel can be rendered in different shapes, and not necessarily square shape.[image: This image shows alternative ways of reconstructing an image from a set of pixel values, using dots, lines, or smooth filtering.]

How can I create image with different shaped pixels in Java?

Below is how I create an Image with Random pixels

```
/**
 * File: RandomImage.java
 * 
 * Description:
 * Create a random color image.
 * 
 * @author King Amada
 * Date: 07-17-20148 tue
 */
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
 public class RandomImage{
   public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{
      //image dimension
      int width = 640;
      int height = 320;
      //create buffered image object img
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      //file object
      File f = null;
      //create random image pixel by pixel
      for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
          int a = (int)(Math.random()*256); //alpha
          int r = (int)(Math.random()*256); //red
          int g = (int)(Math.random()*256); //green
          int b = (int)(Math.random()*256); //blue

          int p = (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b; //pixel

          img.setRGB(x, y, p);
        }
      }
      //write image
      try{
        f = new File("D:\\Image\\Output.png");
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", f);
      }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      }
   }//main() ends here
 }//class ends here
```

Comment: Your code seems to just create and save an image, never rendering it. Do you want to render existing images with differently shaped pixels, like the image in your question, or do you want to save images that specify a pixel shape? I'm afraid the latter's impossible unless you're using something like [DVD anamorphic pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphic_widescreen#DVD_Video)

Comment: In terms of `BufferedImage`, the pixels are stored in an `int[]`, where each index represents the RGB for a pixel in that location. There is no shape or size. This topic seems specific to working with displays, rather than code.

Comment: @AlvarSalokangas if I want to render the an existing picture like the above picture in my question, how will I go about it? would I be able to generate another image and render it like that?

Comment: @kingamada in that case, you want to upscale the image, so each pixel in the source image becomes many pixels in the result image, which will be higher resolution. For example, if 1 pixel became a grid of 3x3 pixels in the result image, you could easily make it so that the corners of each 3x3 "pixel" are transparent, to make plus-shaped pixels, and so on. I would do this with another two nested for-loops inside your for-loops

Comment: @AlvarSalokangas that would result in many pixels as you stated, using 3x3 that would be 9 pixels in total, what if it's a circle shape i want to render?

Comment: @AlvarSalokangas I don't think he wants to simulate it, rather have the pixels in his program render differently without scaling, which since Java doesn't maintain any data about pixel shape, this probably isn't possible via Java's `BufferedImage`. You could probably have your program request the [pixel aspect ratio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio) of the monitor being used, then change your algorithm to best fit whichever format is currently in use.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, is there another method without using BufferedImage if BufferedImage might not be possible?

Comment: No. The pixel ratio is determined by the display, not the software. You could probably determine the aspect ratio by requesting system info (to gain details about the monitors being used), but even then, what would you even do with such info? What is your goal? What do you plan to do by determining the pixel aspect ratio of the monitor? Chances are, you won't be able to change the ratio, so knowing it will only help decide how you should fill the pixel array.

Comment: If your monitor uses RGB, and doesn't support YCbCr, you can't write code to change that. It's built into the monitor. Same goes for pixel aspect ratios: if your monitor doesn't support different ratios, you cannot change it. Keep in mind, this is the aspect ratio for *square* pixel, since most monitors use that strategy for rendering pixels. Other strategies, like lines, would require support from the monitor itself.